# Save Postman Response in Azure DevOps Pipeline in variable or file on the Repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, postman, azure-pipelines

I`m trying to Save Postman Response in Azure DevOps Pipeline in variable or file on the Repo

For example I want to get `pm.variables.get('someID');` and save it to variable or save it to some file in the repo and then I want to run another take of powershell or bash and do some operation with this variable .

but i see that i can not pass varibales from postman to another task

i tried to do something like this :

in the postman i run in the "Test"

```
var delete_id = pm.variables.get('newSiteId');

`log = "##vso[task.setvariable`

 `variable=siteid_delete;isoutput=true]"+delete_id`
```

but im getting error

```
 ##vso[task.setva' contains logging command keyword '##vso', but it's not a legal command. Please see the list of accepted commands: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296
```

Answer (score 0):

> Save Postman Response in Azure DevOps Pipeline in variable or file on the Repo

I am fraid you could not achieve this with postman.

That because the [Logging Commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) is used for the task in Azure devops pipeline, like Powershell instead of postman. That is also the reason why you get the error "keyword '`##vso`', but it's not a legal command." for the postman.

Besides, if you want to save the variable and then want to run another take of powershell or bash and do some operation with this variable, we need to set the varibale in the task or use the REST API update the previous variable.

Comment: Can you please show example of syntax to make this operation ?